# Magento: Display Inventory Levels, filtered by category

Tags: category, stock

Looking at this page and code snippet to display qty on hand on a product page, I'd like to apply this to only certain categories - effectively filter this code snippet by category ID.

http://www.woolleydesign.net/2012/06/magento-show-inventory-levels-on-product-pages/
http://www.woolleydesign.net/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2012/06/default.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Qty on Hand:') ?> <span><!--<?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?>--><?= (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()?></span></p>
```

Replace above code with following:

```
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
            <?php 
                  $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
                  $categories = array(1,2,3,...); // ENTER CERTAIN CATEGORY IDs for which you want to show the 'Qty on Hand:'
                  $flag = 0;
                  foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
                    if (in_array($category_id,$categories))
                      $flag = 1;
                  }
                  if (!$flag): ?>
                     <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Qty on Hand:') ?> <span><!--<?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?>--><?= (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()?></span></p>
            <?php else: ?>
                     <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
```